# How to extract out hair portion only, without changing image size?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an portrait image where I used some k-mean and clustering to get image like this.

[image]

Now I want to extract out the hair portion only which is pointed out by a red dot from following code.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("Image.jpg")

#Detecting Edge of image
Edge = cv2.Canny(img, 100, 150)

Coords = np.nonzero(Edge)

y = np.min(Coords[0])
y = y + 20
h,w,c = img.shape
x = int(w/2)
cv2.circle(img,(x,y), 5, (0,0,255), -1)
cv2.imshow("dot", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And the result of pointed image is:

[image]

However, I want the hair portion, but the image size should not be changed. Because I tried using blob selection and it gave me this result:

[image: Hair]

It changed the image size. But I want the image size to be original size and all the dark pixels except the hair (pointed by red dot) change to white pixel. How to do it?? Is it possible??

## Update:

Here is my code till today:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import dlib
from math import sqrt
import scipy.ndimage as snd



#Facial Landmark Detection
predictor_path = "shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat"
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(predictor_path)

SampleHead = cv2.imread('Test1.jpg')


def facialLandmarks(image):

    detect = detector(image)

    for k, d in enumerate(detect):
        shape = predictor(image, d)

        vec = np.empty([68, 2], dtype=int)
        for b in range(68):
            vec[b][0] = shape.part(b).x
            vec[b][1] = shape.part(b).y

        return vec

def scale(Himage,a1,a2,b1,b2,x1,x2,y1,y2):

    dist1 = sqrt((a2 - a1) ** 2 + (b2 - b1) ** 2)
    # print(dist1)
    dist2 = sqrt((x2 - x1) ** 2 + (y2 - y1) ** 2)
    # print(dist2)
    r = (dist2/dist1)
    # print(r)


    Scaled = cv2.resize(Himage, None, fx=r, fy=r, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

    return Scaled

def edgeDetection(image):
    Edge = cv2.Canny(image, 100, 150)
    Coords = np.nonzero(Edge)

    min_x = np.min(Coords[1])
    min_y = np.min(Coords[0])
    max_x = np.max(Coords[1])
    max_y = np.max(Coords[0])
    return (min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y)

def blurImage(image,V):
    Blurred = cv2.medianBlur(image, V)
    return Blurred


def hairExtraction(blurredImg, minimumY, originalImage):

    # K-mean approach
    Z = blurredImg.reshape((-1, 3))
    Z = np.float32(Z)

    criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)

    K = 4
    ret, label1, center1 = cv2.kmeans(Z, K, None,
                                      criteria, 10,
                                      cv2.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
    center1 = np.uint8(center1)
    res1 = center1[label1.flatten()]
    output1 = res1.reshape((blurredImg.shape))

    x = minimumY + 20
    h,w,c = originalImage.shape
    y = int(w/2)


    # find the index of the cluster of the hair
    mask = label1.reshape(output1.shape[:-1])
    khair = mask[(x, y)]

    # get a mask that's True at all of the indices of hair's group
    hairmask = mask == khair

    # label all connected blobs in hairmask
    bloblab = snd.label(hairmask, structure=np.ones((3, 3)))[0]

    # create a mask for only the hair
    haironlymask = bloblab == bloblab[x, y]

    # get an image with just the hair and then crop it
    justhair = np.where(haironlymask[..., None], originalImage, [255, 255, 255])
    nz = haironlymask.nonzero()
    justhair = justhair[nz[0].min()-5:nz[0].max()+5, nz[1].min()-5:nz[1].max()+5]

    # save the image of just the hair on a white background
    cv2.imwrite("JustHair.jpg", justhair)
    finalHair = cv2.imread("JustHair.jpg")

    # Perform morphology
    se = np.ones((7, 7), dtype='uint8')
    hair = cv2.morphologyEx(finalHair, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, se)

    return hair


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Facial Landmark Detection for SampleHead
    Hlandmarks = facialLandmarks(SampleHead)
    HRightJawlinePoints = (Hlandmarks[0, 0], Hlandmarks[0, 1])
    HLeftJawlinePoints = (Hlandmarks[16, 0], Hlandmarks[16, 1])
    a1 = HRightJawlinePoints[0]
    b1 = HRightJawlinePoints[1]
    a2 = HLeftJawlinePoints[0]
    b2 = HLeftJawlinePoints[1]

    #Scale SampleHead according to size of SampleModel
    Resized = scale(SampleHead,a1,a2,b1,b2,x1,x2,y1,y2)

    #Detecting value of topmost y of resized head
    headExtremeEdgePoints = edgeDetection(Resized)
    headMinY = headExtremeEdgePoints[1]


    # Blurring effect addition
    blurredHeadImage = blurImage(Resized, 5)

    # Hair Extraction
    headHair = hairExtraction(blurredHeadImage, headMinY, Resized)
    cv2.imshow("HeadHair", headHair)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: How did you use blob selection?

Comment: @HaBom, I have updated my post with codes, I have done till now. Please review.

Comment: How about use contour detection and then when you want to draw the contour `drawContours(img, contours, hair_contour_index, (0,255,0), 3);` set image `img` of the same size as the original.

Comment: @Suleiman Could you please elaborate your answer. I am new to image processing.

Comment: With OpenCV [find contour](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html)  you can detect all the shapes (contours) in your image and also eliminate the smaller ones by setting a size threshold limit. Each contour is stored as a vector of points and with the drawContours function you can draw each contour using its index number and draw it on to an image of same size as the original. Check this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46236061/what-are-values-returned-by-findcontour-function-in-opencv-2-4-9).